# Symbol currency

Tags: symbols

Good afternoon

Do you know a latex code for these currencies?

> Vietnamese dong
>
> Polish zloty

Thanks for help.

Comment: [tag/currency](http://www.martin-thoma.de/write-math/tags/currency) and [text search by "vietnam"](http://www.martin-thoma.de/write-math/search/?search=vietnam) and [text search by "poland"](http://www.martin-thoma.de/write-math/search/?search=poland) on write-math.com.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please apologize if this is incorrect, as I don't have any experience with either of these currencies, or how to typeset them. Especially the `z` in front of the zloty might be wrong, but as far as I can tell, this should be correct.

#### Output

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}

z\l

\textdong

\end{document}
```